# JSF ajax call do not work properly in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working in a JSF web application in which i need to refresh specific component on click on some JSF component.
For example :  on my submit command button i want to refresh only **central panel** so i am using the following code.

```
<h:commandButton  value="#{msg['hse.button.submit']}" actionListener="#{roleBean.add}" update="centerContentPanel1" styleClass="button table-search-popup-btn">
</h:commandButton>
```

This code is working fine in Mozilla and IE 11 where only the **centreContentPanel1** is ONLY refreshed but not in Chrome.

I tried using the below command as well

```
<h:commandButton  value="#{msg['hse.button.submit']}" styleClass="button table-search-popup-btn">
<f:ajax execute="sourceID" render="centerContentPanel1" process="@this" listener="#roleBean.add}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

This code is also working fine in Mozilla and IE11 but not in Chrome.

Can anyone give some idea on how to achieve the same behaviour across all browsers with JSF2

Comment: You forgot to tell how exactly it failed in Chrome. By the way, the 1st code snippet is invalid. Perhaps you're confused with PrimeFaces and oversimplifying things by editing the code right in the question without actually testing it?